# $g(x)$ defined by $f(x)$. how to prove that if $f(x)$ is surjective, so is $g(x)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given: $$f:Q \rightarrow Q\backslash\{-1\} \\ g:Q \rightarrow Q\backslash \{1\} \quad;\quad   g(x)={f(x)\over f(x)+1} $$

How does one prove *formaly*:

```
If f is surjevtive(onto), then g is surjective too?
```

Tried simpler example, but still not sure how to write it down:
$$ f:N \rightarrow N \\ g:N \rightarrow N \quad ; \quad g(x)=f(x)+1 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $r \in \Bbb{Q} \setminus\{1\}$. You have to show that there is an $s \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $g(s)=r$. For this to happen, we need
\begin{align*}
g(x) & = r\\
\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1} & = r\\
f(x) & =  \frac{r}{1-r}. 
\end{align*}
Observe that $\frac{r}{1-r} \in \Bbb{Q} \setminus \{-1\}$ (why?).

Now ask yourself, how do we know that we can find an $x$ such that $f$ takes on this value?

Comment: seems similar to what i've written, though i didnt realy understand what i was doing. if i understand correctly: _(r/(1-r)) is in Q\{-1}_ because otherwise _f(x)=-1_, and playing around, we get _0=-1_. i.e. there is no such x. As for _how do we know we can find x so f takes this value_... because its surjective, i.e. there is and x for all values f(x).